# how to find array of string with in a sentence?

Tags: java, arrays

**Situation**

I have an Array of String.    `String[] arr = {"name","name2"};`

**What I want?**

I want to know if there is a function in java which can help to return true if a sentence has one or both of these words.Java's "contains"
 method allow to have only string not an array.

Comment: Use java String.split method to split your sentence into words.. then take each word and see if it's in the array using contains. I'm not doing it for you. Here is how you split your sentence: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you can try this code , i've used the class StringTokenizer of java.util for this problem.

look in the code:

```
public class StackOverFlowProblem {


public static void prn(String message){
    System.out.println(message);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String [] list = {"Hello","My","Friends","How","Are","You"};
    String sentence = "Hey Hello";
    if(searchWordinString(sentence, list))
        prn("exists");
    else
        prn("don't exists");
}

public static boolean searchWordinString(String sentence,String[] list){
    StringTokenizer test = new StringTokenizer(sentence);
    String element ="first iteration";
    while(!element.equals("")){
        try{
            element = test.nextElement().toString();
            prn(element);
            for(int index=0;index<list.length;index++){
                if(element.equals(list[index])){
                    prn(element+"="+list[index]);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            prn("Error: don't exist more words , bye");
            element="";
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

I made a function that takes two parameters, one is a sentence and the other is a list of words.

Inside the function if you find any item in the list of word matches a word of the sentence will return true otherwise be false

Answer (score 1):

If your sentence is stored as a String, then just iterate over the array and check for each word using `compare()`:

```
private static boolean checkForWord(String sentence, String[] words) {
    for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
        if (sentence.contains(words[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; //this statement can only be reached if there is no match
}
```

If the sentence is stored as a String array, then you'll have to iterate over both arrays using nested `for` loops and compare words using `equalsIgnoreCase()` (or just `equals()`, if you want it to be case-sensitive):

```
private static boolean checkForWord(String[] sentence, String[] words) {
    for (int x=0; x<sentence.length; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<words.length; y++) {
            if (sentence[x].equalsIgnoreCase(words[y])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a regular expression, which allows searching for both at the same time, but also allows ensuring that you only search for those exact *words*, not the string within a word, e.g. `firstname`, which `contains()` cannot do.

```
\b(?:name|name2)\b
```

As a Java string literal, you need to double the `\`: `"\\b(?:name|name2)\\b"`

If your list of words is dynamic, i.e. you have an arbitrary array of words, not a hardcoded regex like that, then remember to quote the words when building the regex:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("|", "\\b(?:", ")\\b");
for (String word : words)
    joiner.add(Pattern.quote(word));
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(joiner.toString());
Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Sentence contained word: " + m.group());
}
```

You can even continue searching, to find all instances of such words, by changing the `if` statement to a `while` loop.

You can also add the [`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) option to the [`compile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) call, so it will match `Name` or `NAME` too.